# uniform convergence of $L(s,\chi)$ for $\Re(s) ≥ 1 + \delta$ " due to absolute convergence for $\Re(s)>1$?

Tags: uniform-convergence, dirichlet-series, l-functions

On page 6 of this [link](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~jwsiegel/L-functions.pdf), lemma 2.4 shows $L(s,\chi)$ is absolutely convergent for $\Re(s)>1$.

I understand the proof. However,
they also add: "The above proof also shows that for any $\delta > 0$, the above series converges absolutely
and uniformly for $\Re(s) ≥ 1 + \delta$ "

I do not see why this is the case.

Comment: Note $|n^{-s}|\leq n^{-(1+\delta)}$ for $\Re s\geq 1+\delta$.

Comment: @Wojowu and why does this imply uniform convergence?

Comment: Weierstrass M-test.

Comment: Cool. So here I would let $f_n(x)= \chi(n)/n$ and I can write $|f_n(x)| \leq |n^{-s}| \leq n^{-(1+\delta)} $ for $\Re(s)>1+\delta$

Comment: @Wojowu,  and we know $\sum n^{-(1+\delta)}$ converges